# Firebase List Adapter: error "null object reference"

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to learn to use firebase, but when trying to load data in a listView the application returns the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {my activity} java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.startListening ()' on a **null object reference.**

If someone can see the problem, it would be very helpful.

The aspect of my database:

```
location
   40434734
      latitude: 40.434734
      longitude: -3.70701
      txt: "test"
```

My class:

```
public class start extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView lv;

FirebaseListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location");

    FirebaseListOptions<LocationData> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<LocationData>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.list_location)
            .setQuery(query,LocationData.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
            TextView stdID = v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            LocationData  ld = (LocationData) model;
            stdID.setText(ld.getTxt().toString());
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

My LocationData class to create the object:

```
public class LocationData {

double latitude;
double longitude;
String txt;

public LocationData(){

}
public LocationData(double latitude, double longitude, String txt) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.txt = txt;
}
public String getTxt() {
    return txt;
}

public void setTxt(String txt) {
    this.txt = txt;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Comment: hi , can you please post an image of your current database structure? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  this

```
adapter.startListening();
```

&

```
adapter.stopListening();
```

you can do as -

```
FirebaseListOptions<LocationData> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<LocationData>()
        .setLayout(R.layout.list_location)
        .setQuery(query,LocationData.class)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this) 
        .build();
```

Comment: I hope this has solved your problem. So, plz accept the answer.

Comment: he is doing the right way calling the startListening and stopListening there , read the docs here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md  , i have some examples of listviews working right away as the doc says

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having problems. If I delete adapter.startListening () and adapter.stopListening (), the application does't return any errors, but does't load anything. The layout is empty..

Comment: Use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in populateView method and also i assume you have added setLifecycleOwner(this)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i have added setLifecycleOwner(this) and now i use  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but the result is the same

Comment: Have you added code at github? If yes then you can share the link so i can see the full code.

Answer (score 0):

> com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.startListening ()' on a
>   null object reference.

is telling you that there is no adapter set to startListening, so

Just change this

```
FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
```

to this

```
FirebaseListAdapter<LocationData> adapter;
```

since you are creating the adapter in the wrong way, doing this will allow you to populate it.

The rest of the code is ok as the documentation states